# ReactJS variable change isn't rendering element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a fairly simple situation (I'm using ReactJS with A-Frame / A-Frame React, but that shouldn't really affect anything here).

I have an entity that hints to a user that they can click / swipe an object. I want that entity to disappear after the user has clicked on said object, and then reappear after 10 seconds.

I'm relatively new to React so *may* be doing something wrong here:

1. At the top of my JS file (after my imports, but before the `class` begins, I'm doing `let showHinter = true;`
2. I've got an entity in my `render()` method like this:

   ```
   <AFrameEntity
       events={{
         click: (ev) => {

           showHinter = false;

           setTimeout(() => {
             console.log("showHinter Value:", showHinter)

             /* ↑ This fires, but ↓ this doesn't do anything */

             showHinter = true;
             console.log("showHinter Value:", showHinter)
           }, 5000)

         }
       }}
     >
     </AFrameEntity>
   ```
3. My "hinter" component is a sibling to that, like so:

   ```
   {

     <AFrameEntity /* Bunch of irrelevant stuff here */ >

       // fade out
       {
        !showHinter && 
         <a-animation 
           attribute="material.opacity"
           dur="1000"
           fill="forwards"
           from="1"
           to="0"
           repeat="0"></a-animation>
       }
         //fade in
       {
        showHinter && 
         <a-animation 
           attribute="material.opacity"
           dur="1000"
           fill="forwards"
           from="0"
           to="1"
           repeat="0"></a-animation>
       }
     </AFrameEntity>
   }
   ```

When clicking, `showHinter` is correctly set to false and the element disappears. However, it never re-appears. My console logs *do* happen, and `showHinter === false`, yet my fade-in animation never happens, and inspecting the element with react's devtools shows my fade-out animation entity, and NOT my fade-in one (which should be triggered when `showHinter === true`.

So the basic question is, why isn't React react-ing to my variable change? Do I need to force it to re-render somehow?

Comment: Does `showHinter` belong to React `state`? I do not see your `setState` within your code.

Comment: I made the same mistake at the beginning. Do every change with setState means put your showHinter as a state. this.setState({showHinter: false)} and then check with "this.state.showHinter &&"

Comment: @Tiega Ah yes, you've got it! Post this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do every change, that effect the view or where you expect a re-render, via state.

In your case you do something like(not tested):

```
<AFrameEntity
events={{
  click: (ev) => {

    this.setState({showHinter: false)};

    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("showHinter Value:", this.state.showHinter)

      /* ↑ This fires, but ↓ this doesn't do anything */

      this.setState({showHinter: true)};
      console.log("showHinter Value:", this.state.showHinter)
    }, 5000)

  }
}}
```

And check the state in your render function.

```
{

  <AFrameEntity /* Bunch of irrelevant stuff here */ >

    // fade out
    {
     !this.state.showHinter && 
      <a-animation 
        attribute="material.opacity"
        dur="1000"
        fill="forwards"
        from="1"
        to="0"
        repeat="0"></a-animation>
    }
      //fade in
    {
     this.state.showHinter && 
      <a-animation 
        attribute="material.opacity"
        dur="1000"
        fill="forwards"
        from="0"
        to="1"
        repeat="0"></a-animation>
    }
  </AFrameEntity>
}
```